# U-Boot script for choosing the most recent image

Tags: linux, flash, embedded-linux, u-boot

I have a u-boot which copies a multiimage (Linux kernel+rootfs+dts) from a serial FLASH to the DDR. The device is remotely powered. The device requires fail safe remote firmware upgrade which survives power failure. I always keep two images on the FLASH. While I write a new firmware to the FLASH there is always another, older, firmware image on the FLASH. U-boot after power up shall boot the most recent firmware.

Boot time is important, but not critical. For example, I thought to let u-boot to boot the first "valid" image. A Linux application would decide if a reboot is required and modify u-boot environment.

I can patch u-boot - add a command which finds the most recent firmware on the FLASH. I would expect that somebody somewhere already solved this problem and likely better than me. Is there a patch/script for u-boot which allows to automatically choose the latest firmware based on some metadata?

Any other approaches to the problem?

Comment: *"I always keep two images on the FLASH"* -- I would improve upon that scheme by storing the kernel and dtb images as files in a **/boot** directory in the rootfs. Then you get flash wear-leveling, updates are nondestructive to previous versions, and can have more than just two versions.  The vulnerability to power failure is reduced to just a few rename operations instead of the entire update procedure.

Comment: @sawdust This is a great advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
Use Uboot's [bootcount](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootBootCountLimit) feature.
It increments every boot retry. and is supposed to be cleared by an application on the filesystem after the kernel was booted.
If it reached a a threshold. you can then boot another image from uboot.